# Difference between "default" and "default!" in C#

Tags: c#, record

On [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) particular page of documentation to do with record types. I noticed on the second example of code that the keyword `default` was used with the null forigiving operator. The example is shown below:

```
public record Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; init; } = default!;
    public string LastName { get; init; } = default!;
};
```

To my knowledge, the default value for a string type should be `null`. But if there is a null forgiving operator appended to the default operator, what does it actually do?

Does it make an empty string or is it still null?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving it doesn't do anything, merely telling the compiler to not emit the warning

Comment: Using `default!` basically makes a mockery of `#nullable` annotations. In the case of `record Person` above, it means that a `new Person()` will have `FIrstName == null`, which is _just wrong_. Consumers of that `Person` will expect those String properties to be never-null, and yet, _they are_ - which will lead to a lovely `NullReferenceException` that could have easily been prevented. (This is what constructors are meant for... and yet so many C# devs are seemingly _allergic_ to constructors or concepts like class-invariants and postconditions... has the world gone mad?)

Answer (score 1):

! is null-forgiving operator. [docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving)
"Available in C# 8.0 and later, the unary postfix ! operator is the null-forgiving, or null-suppression, operator. In an enabled nullable annotation context, you use the null-forgiving operator to declare that expression x of a reference type isn't null: x!."